# Is there any documentation or case study of scaling up an Open Data API?

Tags: api, releasing-data, best-practice

Forecasting open data demand is quite challenging. A new public dataset means more downloads, a new app results in way more requests.

It would be interesting to discuss the throughput of open data portals, in terms of datasets downloads or API calls.

Has anyone done a research in this matter?

Comment: You can contact this group, who have created an API for Swiss Public Transport data: http://transport.opendata.ch/

Comment: awesome, thanks, I'll shoot them an email and post the findings in here.

Comment: I would assume that both Socrata and the CKAN/DKAN communities would have information about this ... I just don't know if they've published anything on it.

Comment: Adding a little to @Joe's comment, CKAN and Socrata both, indeed, have tracking and analytics built in though I do not think either are public by default. You can read more about Socrata analytics at great blog post by Thomas Levine: http://thomaslevine.com/!/socrata-metrics-api/ [disclosure: my company is a partner of Socrata but we use CKAN sometimes too]

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the main data portal in the UK: [data.gov.uk](http://data.gov.uk/data/site-usage#totals)

An example of the published statistics is below.

```
Dataset                                         Views   Downloads
English Indices of Deprivation 2010             45173   15046
Bona Vacantia Unclaimed Estates and Adverts     38263   24112
Lower Layer Super Output Area (LSOA) boundaries 35547    8785
```